# Single DbContext or multiple DbContexts for db with a few hundred tables?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am part of a 4 person team looking after a large legacy application that was recently converted to .Net Core.

At the moment, our data access is done with a home grown semi-ORM, which is terrible. We want to migrate to EF Core, Code First.

Our database has about 200 tables. The schema has grown ad hoc over 15+ years, so there is no real "architecture".

Some of us want to put all tables definitions into the one DbContext, to keep maintenance simple. Others want to split the tables over several DbContexts because in their view a single DbContext with lots of tables will give us bad performance.

Maintainability is a real issue for us, because 1) with our customers, introducing a bug can quickly lead to a lot of pain; and 2) we need to be able to build new features quickly with a small team to stay ahead of the competition. On the other hand, severe performance degradation is not acceptable.

Would it be better to stick all 200 tables in the one DbContext, or would it be better to split them over multiple DbContexts?

Comment: You can always split them later. [Here is an interesting post on bounded contexts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj883952.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Bounded contexts will reduce the "spin up" time for the DB Contexts. 200 tables isn't necessarily a reason to consider them, it will depend more on the number of relationships mapped between the tables. Performance issues around large contexts typically has more to do with contexts tracking more data than needed and living longer than needed, but large, complex model structures can potentially add seconds to requests.

When considering a bounded context structure you will want to choose areas to ensure that requests can be served by a single context. Avoid situations where multiple contexts need to be spun up to serve a request, or entities can be shared between contexts. This can be tricky if your code is adopting patterns like Generic Repositories.  if the existing code is using generic repositories you will generally be better off using a single DbContext because those repositories will want to talk to a single DbContext and it can be too easy to end up with controller/service code that is inadvertently spawning multiple contexts or passing entity references with references that are tracked (or not) by different DbContexts.

When working with bounded contexts I use essentially a bounded set of repositories that have a more "vertical" profile where a particular controller will have its own repository which serves the main and supporting entities for that controller. One or more controllers/repositories will be serviced by a bounded DbContext.